# Spice simulation of 555 flasher will not oscillate

Tags: 555, pulse, ngspice

I am hoping that this is a very simple question. [image: Circuit]

I am trying to simulate the circuit in ngspice, but it seems that the oscillation will not initiate. I delayed the on pulse, but the expected 20Hz square wave does not appear.[image]
I have spent an inordinate amount of time just because I am old stubborn. I might just have to build it first, but I am rearranging my stuff.
Thanks a lot for your help. 
Note: the V1 pulse brings up the power supply after the simulation starts.
[image: talking electronics]
Circuit with a generic 555 timer.
[image: datasheet]
Circuit description from ICM7555.

Comment: try this one ... https://www.electroschematics.com/8443/555-led-flasher/

Comment: Shouldn't there be a path from the discharge pin to ground somewhere?  Otherwise, it'll just charge the capacitor, then switch to discharge mode but the current has nowhere to go...

Comment: Where are you getting your 555 model? I've had trouble with poor or non performance of 555 models in ngspice.

Comment: @Jules I believe here it's discharging the capacitor through the output pin, which isn't too unusual in 555 circuits.

Comment: Some working ngspice examples:
https://sourceforge.net/p/ngspice/discussion/ngspice-tips/thread/d2048be2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really looks like a bad SPICE models in Ngspice, I simulated your circuit in LTspice with Bordodynov model library and it worked

Comment: I tried it in ltspice and it worked fine. Thanks. ltspice makes it easy to initiate the oscillation. I tried another 555 model in ngspice to no avail.